# Repaint seems not working when called multiple times from the same method

Tags: geotools

I have the following scenario:


`displaySelectedFeatures(IDs);

then some code... and then:

displaySelectedFeatures(features);`

Display selected features looks like this:

```
public void displaySelectedFeatures(Map<Color, Set<FeatureId>> features) {

    Style style;

    style = createSelectedStyle(features);

    Layer layer = mapFrame.getMapContent().layers().get(0);
    ((FeatureLayer) layer).setStyle(style);

    mapFrame.getMapPane().repaint();    
}
```

What I need is the following. First IDs object should be drawn and then after some time e.g. 5 seconds, object - features should be repainted.
What happens it that only the IDs is drawn while features(second repaint) is omitted.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the renderer doesn't think you have changed anything, so it doesn't bother to do the second redraw. Try adding a second layer for the highlights and change the features directly.